# How do you format a horizontal list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to print a formatted horizontal list after a prompt. This is what I've tried:

```
def displayList(prompt, list_):
    print(f"{prompt:>20}:",*list_, sep = f"{'':>4}")
```

but when displaying multiple lists on top of each other I get this:

```
              List 1:    6    2    4    8    4
              List 2:    6    3    5    9    1
          Added List:    12    5    9    17    5
     Multpilied List:    36    6    20    72    4
```

but I want this:

```
              List 1:     5    4    8    6    4  

              List 2:     4    9   10    1    2  

          Added List:     9   13   18    7    6  

     Multpilied List:    20   36   80    6    8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply a field width to each list item rather than a fixed-width separator. For example:

```
print(f'{prompt:>20}:' + ', '.join(f'{e:>10}' for e in list_))
```